# PayPal button/form not showing numbers correctly from input field

Tags: html, excel, input, paypal

I have a simple PayPal button where I ask user to enter a 15 digits numbers and make a purchase. This number may start with a "0" like sample: **013408006153464**

When I get email from PayPal the number shows correctly in email but I am not able to search my email box with this number. If I do a search then it will not find the PayPal email by this number.

And when download a CSV file from PayPal then Excel is showing this number as: 1.3408E+13 and when I click on this number then in Excel bar its showing as: 13408006153464 (Here its missing the "0" in start)

Here is my PayPal input field for this number:

```
<td><input maxlength="15" name="os1" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" /></td>
```

As you see its using `type="text"` if I change it to: `type="number"` then it will NOT get the first digit if its "0" ?

Any suggestion what I shall do to see the number correctly in Excel and be able to search my email box on MAC OSX Mail?

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Put an ' in the beginning of the text, for example '013408006153464.
  then Excel will not remove the 0.

I hope it helps you